# Finding only active items from a column of 'added' / 'removed'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to write a query that tries to find the most recent items.

Given a set of parent_service_items find the relevant child service items and return a list of them. For finding just the direct children, I'm using query which simply finds all the associated children. I then use this query in a recursive postgres function that goes until no children are left.

My goal is to update this to handle the case of last item being removed. Take this case for example.

```
epic 1 
 ticket 1
    links (added, removed)
 ticket 2
    links (added)

epic 2
 ticket 1
    links (added)
 ticket 2
    links (added)
```

If given epic 1 as a parent id, only ticket 2 should be returned. If given epic 1 and epic 2 as parent ids, ticket 1 and ticket 2 should be returned. The above query currently gives both ticket 1 and ticket 2 for epic 1.

As you can imagine with jira, these examples get far more complex. Any ideas on how best to filter this so that we only include a ticket if the most recent action was added. The table includes both an action_key which is a string of 'added' or 'removed', and a timestamp.

thanks.

Sample Data:

service_items

| id | item_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | epic |
| 2 | epic |
| 3 | card |
| 4 | card |

service_item_links

| link_type | parent_service_item | child_service_item | action_date | action_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'has_child' | 1 | 3 | '2020-01-01 00:00:00' | 'added' |
| 'has_child' | 1 | 3 | '2020-01-02 00:00:00' | 'removed' |
| 'has_child' | 1 | 3 | '2020-01-03 00:00:00' | 'added' |
| 'has_child' | 1 | 4 | '2020-01-01 00:00:00' | 'added |
| 'has_child' | 2 | 3 | '2020-01-01 00:00:00' | 'added' |
| 'has_child' | 2 | 4 | '2020-01-01 00:00:00' | 'added' |

Is sample data for the above example.

Given the parent id of 1, the child id of 4 should be returned.

given the parent ids of {1,2}, the child if of 3 and 4 should be returned.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Added some example data and desired outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a row is removed can't be added again,
here is how you can achieve that :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.child_service_item, action_date
FROM
    service_item_links t
WHERE
    t.parent_service_item IN (1, 2)
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            service_item_links t2
        WHERE
            t2.parent_service_item = t.parent_service_item
            AND t2.child_service_item = t.child_service_item
            AND t.action_key = 'removed'
    );
```

If the row can be added later on again you need to find out last action_type on that :

```
;WITH cte AS (
     SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(action_key) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_service_item, child_service_item ORDER BY action_date DESC) last_action_type
     FROM service_item_links
)

    SELECT parent_service_item, child_service_item, MAX(action_date) AS action_date
    FROM cte 
    WHERE last_action_type ='added'
    AND parent_service_item IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY cte.parent_service_item, child_service_item
```

Comment: What about the case where service_item_links has an action_date. I updated the example to include times, and a new row where ticket 1 was added back after it was removed. In that case, it should show with {1,2} being entered in.

Comment: @TimMcGee updated my answer , hopefully its what you need